# JSP web application :javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

In my eclipse IDE everything is Ok But when i export it as WAR and deploy in remote server this error comes on run time

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/JavadocQualifiedTypeReference
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:348)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/JavadocQualifiedTypeReference

Comment: i think your servlet classes are conflicting, if you have servlet class in your war file, create your war file without servlet class.the server already has servlet class.

Comment: Hi ihsan  thanks for your suggestion...I had two  WAR files both had same name servlets...i removed one ...but still getting same errors

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by myself. Renamed the servlet and the references and mappings too.
but i was thinking even if name be same wont those two servlets in two different WAR files be considered as two different entity. Thanks Ihsan for making me think in that way too